# PWA issue - nothing happens after clicking on 'Add to homescreen'

Tags: javascript, html, json

I just started to get into web apps and came across this problem.
I converted web worker example into pwa and i managed to save app onto my desktop but later on the same thing didn't work
On chrome after clicking 'Add to homescreen' all I get is 'Service Worker Registered' and nothing happens from there.
Think that issue is in .js files but can't figure it out.

Here are my files:

main.html

```
<html>
<head>

   <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
 </head>
   <button onclick="sayHI()">Say HI</button>
   <button onclick="unknownCmd()">Send unknown command</button>
   <button onclick="stop()">Stop worker</button>
   <output id="result"></output>

   <script>
     function sayHI() {
      worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'start', 'msg': 'Hi'});
     }

 function stop() {
   // worker.terminate() from this script would also stop the worker.
   worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'stop', 'msg': 'Bye'});
     }

     function unknownCmd() {
       worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'foobard', 'msg': '???'});
     }

     var worker = new Worker('work_jedan.js');

     worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
       document.getElementById('result').textContent = e.data;
     }, false);
   </script>
<body>
        <script src="app.js" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
             .register('./work_jedan.js')
             .then(function() { console.log('Service Worker Registered');

            });

  }

})();
self.addEventListener('fetch', function() {});
```

work_jedan.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
   var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'start':
      self.postMessage('WORKER STARTED: ' + data.msg);
      break;
    case 'stop':
      self.postMessage('WORKER STOPPED: ' + data.msg +
                   '. (buttons will no longer work)');
      self.close(); // Terminates the worker.
      break;
    default:
      self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + data.msg);
  };
}, false);
```

mainfest.json

```
    {
  "name": "Primjer",
  "short_name": "pr",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "img12.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    }],
  "start_url": "/main.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#3E4EB8",
  "theme_color": "#2F3BA2"
}
```

Comment: Java? Looks more like JavaScript to me

Comment: changed now, thanks for noticing :)